Getting a comment with Youtube V3 API
I'm using the Youtube v3 Data API to get a comment.
When I press Populate APIs explorer, it gives error 403 The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list
My quota is only at 0.02% usage at the moment. Is there any reason for this? Other API calls seem to work fine.
Made sure to check OAuth 2.0 and have a valid API key also.

You can request a quota increase at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota.

I have 9998 units remaing, still have the same error

As far as I remember the quota monitoring is quite unclear, maybe wait 24 hours and try again.

Use your Apikey for testing. Sometimes that page fails with OAuth

I have tried without OAuth as well but same issue. I have submitted a bug report to Google as it's an issue on their end https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/355980074

I figured out the issue, it was caused by using the wrong scope when authorizing.
I was using youtube.readonly when it should be youtube.force-ssl. I believe the API explorer was also using the last authorized token which explains this behaviour as well, but it is annoying that they say the error is related to quota since that is not correct.
